# linux c socket send multicast broadcast and receive self

Tags: c, sockets, networking, broadcast

I want to judge if the network is error, So I send multicast broadcast(239.255.255.250:1900) interval. 
In the same time, I listen this port. if I can receive myself multicast broadcast, I think the network is ok. if i can't receive myself multicast broadcast many times, I think the network is error.
I think this solution is ok.
but My colleague say it is error, because myself multicast broadcast is received by myself will not from network, it will from myself IP Layer.  myself multicast broadcast send to myself will just in myself computer, it will not in the outside network.
Is that Right?    other times, how can I judge if the network is error with loop

Comment: You are using a multicast heartbeat message as a way to detect if there is a network problem, and you are using the same machine to listen for the same message. You reason if you can receive the message, the network must be ok. Your colleague believes this solution does not work because the message you received was internally delivered by the machine's IP stack. If your colleague is right, you want to know what you should do instead to detect a network problem.

Comment: @jxh yes. Thank you first. but First I want to know my colleague is right? Second I want to know If my colleague is right, There is other way to detect if there is a network problem?

Comment: Please show some actual code of how you are accomplishing this, and we can see if your implementation has problems. Probably, it would help to see your route table too and any ip table/forwarding rules you may have installed as well.

Comment: @jxh I use the libupnp. I use the interface which is provied by libupnp. the code is too long .... but i can sure the implementation is right, the WireShark and log print show the right. the route table and the ip table/forwarding can not show, because this library will be used in android ios and windows. Sorry

Comment: For starters, please define by what you mean by "judge if the network is in error"?  If the device is properly connected to the LAN or wifi, but one of the upstream routers is disconnected, does that constitute as an error?  What are you **really** trying to do by detecting if the network is in error?

Comment: @selbie many times In android and ios, If I changed the wifi, turn off the wifi long time, then connect or sleep long time and many random situation; the socket is can used to send, but it can not receive any data; I don't know the android or ios implementation, but the socket really can not receive any data or send any data(api **send** no error return).I want to detect this error with loop

Comment: @selbie so I want to send the broadcast myself, and to test if myself can receive this packet to detect if the network error